# I made new login names when i upgraded now I can't see files on external drive

Tags: permissions, files

Upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 was successful and I thought everything was good.  I decided to do a complete wipe and start from scratch so I off loaded everything to an external drive.  I thought I was safe.  Not thinking when I installed 12.0.4 I created a new Admin user and a new User for myself.  I wanted to use aliases instead of my name in the computer.  Today I reconnected the external drive to access a spreadsheet.  I did get a message that said some files were not readable.  Also my user file could only see some music folders I created for ripping LPs to CDs but not my data files.  Also the Admin user could not even see the external drive.  I thought a file was a file on an external drive and didn’t even think about permissions associated to a login.  Did I shoot myself in the foot when I created new user names?  Is there anyway I can access my old files.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, not being able to see some files seems kind of weird. You may need to change ownership of everything (as long as these are just files from your /home folder and not important ones that depend on their ownership like /etc files) To do a recursive change of ownership I believe
 `find /path/to/external -exec chown Admin:Admin {} \;`
Change the /path/to/external to the path to the external drive, and Admin to the exact username you want to have access to the files.

The syntax for find can be funny like the escaped colon and the brackets, but it should work. Find just lists all files and folders if not given a specific -name to look for, the -exec flag tells find you want to run some other shell command and pass through one at a time the files it finds, the {} is the place holder where each file name will be passed and then the command will be run. You may need a sudo or two in there.

Also have you tried to `sudo su root` and look around like that? Though this is from the command line not from the gui.